# How to load assets from a folder other than the web default folder?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

**This is my architecture folders :**

[image: This is my architecture folders]

I would like to load an picture using `asset()` in a twig template which is located in

`sites/sf2.local/views/index.html.twig`

and the picture is in

`sites/sf2.local/assets/img/logo_om.gif`

So in my config.yml I have added this line :

```
assetic:
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/../sites/sf2.local/assets/
```

but it doesn't work, I can't load the picture using :

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/logo_om.gif') }}" alt="img" />
```

in the twig template..

How can I do this ?

Comment: What path does this `asset('img/logo_om.gif')` generate?

Comment: `<img src="/img/logo_om.gif" alt="img">`

Comment: I have added the explanation and possible solution so check it out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you have mistaken `assets` for `assetic`. Twig function `asset` does nothing more than making you assets absolute. It does not affect where those assets are read from. That is described in this docs:

[Linking to assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

On the other hand, `assetic` describes where compiled (and optionally filtered, merged, uglified, etc...) resources are read from. That only applies to `JS` and `CSS`.

### Possible solution:

Open Terminal, navigate to your `web` symlink that directory:

```
cd /.../sf2/web
ln -s ../sites/sf2.local/assets/img
ln -s ../sites/sf2.local/assets/js
ln -s ../sites/sf2.local/assets/css
```

Now you have 3 additional **symlinks** (not copies) in your web and using `asset('img/some-pic.png')` actually targets the symlinked `img` directory.

**Is this symlinking acceptable?**

### Alternative solution (whole assets):

```
cd /.../sf2/web
ln -s ../sites/sf2.local/assets
```

and use it:

```
asset('assets/img/some-pic.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explication, it works :) but there is not an other solution that using symlinks ? because for every new folder I have to execute this command...

Comment: Glad I could help. ;) You could symlink the whole `../sites/sf2.local/assets` and use as `asset('assets/img/some-pic.png')`. That way you would not need to `symlink` some future directories ;)

Comment: Yes, anyway I do not see any other solution.. Thanks :)